# android error in install - Permission Denied

Tags: android, visual-studio, mono

i get error "Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Permission Denied" while installing mono application from Visual Studio on devices that have android 4.1.x and upper version. in lower version i have no problem and app installed successfully

detail description: after first install, in visual studio i get below error too: "There is a shared runtime on the device whose version cannot be determined. A new runtime will not be deployed. If the runtime needs to be replaced, please manually remove it from the device. There is a platform support runtime on the device whose version cannot be determined. A new platform support runtime will not be deployed. If the platform support runtime needs to be replaced, please manually remove it from the device."

then after pressing ok,mono is installing on device,but i get Permission Denied error

error detail attached.

how can i fix it? thanks
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From what I read [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11383/deployment-failed-due-to-an-error-in-fastdev-assembly-synchronization), it seems to be an issue with the fast deployment option. I turned it off by going to Project / Project Options / Android Build / Fast deployment and it worked fine after that.